# How can I adapt my topology around beveled corners?

Tags: mesh, topology

I'm trying to model an arcade cabinet but my topology is horrible and I feel like there must be a better way of doing this.

How can I improve my topology on this cabinet?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong,however, I've attached some images that show the Arcade cabinet and its awful topology.

[image: Image1]

:[image: Image2][image]
[image][image]

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you have more details edit the original and add any relevant information there. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's horrible, maybe you don't need so many edges on your bevels, and maybe add some additional edge loops through the shape with the knife tool, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you creating a simple mesh it is important to use only quadrilaterals to preserve the face and edge loops. First create the meshs base shape from a cube with extruding and face inserting. When you use beveling never bevel only one edge, always select a whole ring, because otherwise you will get non-quadrilateral faces then you can't use loop cut and other loop tools well. If you beveling perpendicular edges always use even number for the cuts to avoid the non-quadrilateral faces. If you want to fill new faces I recommend the gridfill tool.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by selecting a whole ring?

Comment: as you can see on the two middle pictures

Comment: Okay thank you, but my arcade is a little more complicated, It's hard to see but the sidepanels are sort of extruded and the logo panel is also has some extrusion. I've tried to make it look similar to a Zaxxon Classic arcade cabinet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQGyMDDFhwA&t=6s Here's a video showcasing what it looks like, would the same principles follow or do I need to think of something else?